# Merge pandas dfs columns if values overlap, otherwise assign default value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dfs

df1

```
val dat
1   0
2   0
3   100
4   100
5   50
6   4
```

df2

```
val
3
5
```

I want to make a new column df1[both], with values overlapping with between df1[val] and df2[val] and non-overlapping values are assigned a default value = 0

```
val dat both
1   0   0
2   0   0
3   100 3
4   100 0
5   50  5
6   4   0
```

How do I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and new column `both` by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and then replace missing values:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2.assign(both = df2['val']), how='left').fillna({'both':0})
print (df1)
   val  dat  both
0    1    0   0.0
1    2    0   0.0
2    3  100   3.0
3    4  100   0.0
4    5   50   5.0
5    6    4   0.0
```

Or  if need integers use:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2.assign(both = df2['val']), how='left').fillna({'both':0})
df1['both'] = df1['both'].astype(int)
print (df1)
   val  dat  both
0    1    0     0
1    2    0     0
2    3  100     3
3    4  100     0
4    5   50     5
5    6    4     0
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to `merge` both dataframes, and use the result from the `indicator` column to `map` to either `0` or the value `val`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left',on='val', indicator='both')
df['both'] = df.both.eq('both').mul(df.val)

print(df)
   val  dat  both
0    1    0     0
1    2    0     0
2    3  100     3
3    4  100     0
4    5   50     5
5    6    4     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.where`:

```
df["both"] = df["val"].where(df["val"].isin(df2["val"]), 0)

print (df)

   val  dat  both
0    1    0     0
1    2    0     0
2    3  100     3
3    4  100     0
4    5   50     5
5    6    4     0
```

Comment: Here best solution, plus1